# How to programatically get all wiki pages? In sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, web-services, csom, jsom

How to get all wiki pages in all collections or in one collection?

I'm trying REST for search, but when i send empty query I get no results.

Comment: It might help if you show us the code your tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve all the Wiki pages in a site collection using Search api in REST.

use the below query to get your wiki pages.

`https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Site:https://domain.sharepoint.com/+ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C*'&rowlimit=10`

Comment: I'm using only 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2* as CT definition, but answer is correct.

Comment: Also relevant CT for wiki pages 0x010108006E9247ECFB2EF24A92388976E017CAB8